# Hint or infer the return type for RSpec let() implementing FactoryGirl create()

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rubymine, yard

Using RubyMine, in an rspec test, is there a way to let RubyMine know the type of the created object (for auto-completion and 'cannot find ' warning suppression?

eg:

```
# @yieldreturn [Tibbees::Tibbee]
let!(:tibbee) {
  create(:tibbee,
         canonical_vendible: article_vendible,
         owner: tibbee_user)
}
```

RubyMine doesn't seem to recognise @yieldreturn (and I'm not sure if that's correct anyhow) and I've had no luck with @type and @return.

The

```
let!(:tibbee) { create(...) || Tibbees::Tibbee.new }
```

cludge works, but yuk.  Any advice greatly appreciated.  Perhaps there's even a way to let the factories take care of it, but that seems 'too deep' an abstraction to be likely to be picked up by RubyMine?

Answer (score 0):

*Not an immediate solution, but:*

While google on this, I came across https://github.com/JetBrains/ruby-type-inference which holds great promise for the future, that is probably relevant to anyone with an interest in this question.

From the README:

> ruby-type-inference project is a completely new approach to tackle the problems Ruby dynamic nature by providing more reliable symbol resolution and type inference.

In answer to some questions I asked them:

> We are going to make the plugin working and publicly available with 2017.3 release though it will definitely be in "beta" since several problems are yet to be solved even on the theoretical side. For everything to work real properly we have to rework our type system on IDE side which is most likely not going to be completed in 2017.
>
> It might be run at the moment, however ... the results are more of experimental value ... [and] it will be difficult to use it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old request, but updating for future reference with discussion at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-19907:

As of today (RubyMine 2021.2.3, Build #RM-212.5457.52) Rubymine can now introspect the correct type for FactoryBot create within a let, so that:

let(:name) { create(:some_model)} now has the type inferred correct from the factory.

However it would still be useful to be able to annotate a let that can't be introspected (maybe it's not calling FactoryBot).

But the suggestion of @yieldreturn seems wrong - that's for methods that take a block. But it would be nice if you could annotate let(:whatever){} with @return tag. Compare https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#yieldreturn with https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#return